# How do I sort by the second field (numbers) only?

Tags: linux, file, sorting, csv, unix

How do I sort by the second field (numbers) only?
This: "sort -k 2n", doesn't work.

By second field I meant the field right after the comma in a csv file, which is the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -k 2n -t ',' file
```

You should use `-t` to change the delimiter.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I tried that and it worked! Thanks!